# Trying to get Cum GPA to correctly display single GPA for every record in a single Term and subsequent Term where the criteria was not met

Tags: sql, database

I'm currently trying to calculate CUM GPA that would give me the correct CUM GPA and apply that number to each record in a Term while also correctly calculating the CUM GPA in subsequent terms where the criteria was not met.

For some context, there was a request to get CUM CREDITS after we transitioned to REPORTING TERMS (Combined all individual terms into one Ex. FA1 and FA2 are now grouped as FAR) and that screwed the calculations for CUM GPA as well. The CUM CREDITS seems to be working just fine but the CUM GPA is giving me issues.

For example:

1. The student I'm using took classes in (2023SU1) and has a CUM GPA of 3.14 (which is correct) and is reflected in the database table
2. This same student took another class in to which they got a B+ in (2023SU2) which brought their CUM GPA to 3.16
3. The student withdrew from classes in (2023FA1) but because they were enrolled the record still needs reflect their CUM GPA as of the last time they completed any course work and the table should reflect that by having the same CUM GPA of 3.16 as (2023SU2) record. The (2023FA2) record is negligible because it would update to the correct CUM GPA until grades are transcripted by the Registrar at the end of the term.

The problem I need resolved is how to get (2023FA1) and any subsequent records where a student doesn't receive a transcritped grade to reflect the correct CUM GPA based on the last term that they did.

I've attached a couple screenshots of the correct data if needed:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h55y.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkbpi.png)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPchP.png)

Here is what I put together that gets me the correct CUM GPA for each semester the student completed coursework and its output:

```
Select cc.STC_PERSON_ID, cc.STC_TERM, cc.STC_GRADE, cc.STC_ACAD_LEVEL, cc.GRADE_VALUE, cc.CUMULATIVE_CREDITS, cc.CUMULATIVE_GPA, cc.STC_END_DATE
--INTO #TEMP --Drop Table #TEMP
From SPT_STUDENT_ACAD_CRED sac
INNER JOIN (
    Select STC_PERSON_ID, STC_TERM, STC_GRADE, GRADE_VALUE, STC_ATT_CRED, STC_REPL_CODE, STC_ACAD_LEVEL, STC_COURSE, STC_END_DATE,
            SUM(STC_CUM_CONTRIB_CMPL_CRED) OVER (PARTITION BY STC_PERSON_ID, STC_ACAD_LEVEL 
                                          ORDER BY STC_PERSON_ID,  
                                                   STC_END_DATE,  
                                                   STC_ACAD_LEVEL) AS CUMULATIVE_CREDITS,   
        NULLIF(SUM(GRADE_VALUE * STC_ATT_CRED) OVER (PARTITION BY STC_PERSON_ID, STC_ACAD_LEVEL  
                                          ORDER BY STC_PERSON_ID,  
                                                   STC_END_DATE,  
                                                   STC_ACAD_LEVEL),0)
        / SUM(STC_CRED) OVER (PARTITION BY STC_PERSON_ID, STC_ACAD_LEVEL  
                                          ORDER BY STC_PERSON_ID,  
                                                   STC_END_DATE,  
                                                   STC_ACAD_LEVEL)
                                          AS CUMULATIVE_GPA 
    From SPT_STUDENT_ACAD_CRED
    WHERE STC_GRADE IS NOT NULL
    AND STC_GRADE NOT LIKE 'W'
    AND STC_REPL_CODE IS NULL
    AND STC_ATT_CRED IS NOT NULL
    AND STC_PERSON_ID = '0742967' 
        ) cc
    On sac.STC_PERSON_ID = cc.STC_PERSON_ID and sac.STc_TERM = cc.STC_TERM and sac.STC_ACAD_LEVEL = cc.STC_ACAD_LEVEL AND sac.STC_COURSE = cc.STC_Course AND sac.STC_END_DATE = cc.STC_END_DATE
    ORDER BY STC_END_DATE
```

[Output of above block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGPH2.png)

So what I thought might work is putting those results into a temp (see the commented out INTO statement) table and updating the main table on a couple fields. Here's that code:

```
UPDATE E27_STUDENT_TERM_INFO_TEST 
SET CUMULATIVE_CREDITS = temp.CUMULATIVE_CREDITS, CUMULATIVE_GPA = temp.CUMULATIVE_GPA
From #TEMP temp
WHERE TEMP.STC_PERSON_ID = STTR_STUDENT and TEMP.STC_TERM = STTR_TERM and TEMP.STC_ACAD_LEVEL = STTR_ACAD_LEVEL And Temp.STC_END_DATE = ENROLLMENT_END_DATE
```

[Output of 2nd block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pcfY.png)

So what I would need to see is 2023FA1 have the same CUM GPA as 2023SU2 because the student withdrew from classes in 2023FA1 and thus earned no new grades and 2023FA2 has not been transcripted yet which would mean that it wouldn't update to the correct CUM GPA until grades are submitted and would simply reflect the last transcripted record which, in this example, is the incorrect 2023FA1 record.

I tried explaining it as best as I could just to get this post completed but if anyone needs further clarification I will be sure to respond. Thank you for looking.

Comment: Screenshots of data are not helpful. Please provide example DDL/DML that can be copied. `DECLARE @Table TABLE (Col1 INT, Col2 DATE, ...); INSERT INTO @Table (Col1, Col2, ...) VALUES (1, '2023-12-05', ...), (2, '2023-12-06', ...);` Please tag the appropriate dialect (mySQL, PostGreSQL, SQL Server?)